# Get user-agent in getStaticProps in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, user-agent

we want to get user-agent in getStaticProps for logs

We are adding a access and error log in our project. So in logs we want to add user-agent also. So we are using getStaticProps in our project. I want to access user-agent in that. I try by using adding user agent in search query by using middleware, it worked but it will make different files with same data in cache so that we dont want. And also the context we use in getStaticProps didnt have req and res object so we can't get user-agent from req.

Comment: You can't get `user-agent` in `getStaticProps` - it used to pre-render the page before the website is deployed, and therefore, has no knowledge of request. If you need to get `user-agent`, use either middleware, `getServerSideProps`, or log data on client-side.

Answer (score 0):

`getStaticProps` won't have any data about the user agent, be cause it gets compiled and [statically served](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props#when-does-getstaticprops-run).

I don't know what you need the user agent for exactly, but you have a few options to get its value:

- using a [Middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware) that would run before a request to your static page
- `getServerSideProps` that would allow you to have `req` and [associated headers](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)
- sending data from the client side (some query to your server)
- using third party apps like [Google Analytics](https://analytics.withgoogle.com/) or any other app that allows you to track browser values (you could have stats about how many users use a certain user agent and so on)